# Who passes the response to the user in the MVC architecture? The controller or the view?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I saw many resources online with different graphics about MVC architecture. Some of them show that the View component passes the presentation to the Controller and the Controller provides the user with the response; like this: [first graph](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20220224160807/Model1.png)
[image: see how the View fetches the presentation and the controller sends the response]

The other ones show that the View component directly presents the results to the user without interacting with the controller; like this: [second graph](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20210629165722/mvc.png) [image: see here how the view sends the response directly to the user and the controller only interacts with the model and passes data to view]

This confused me a lot, especially after seeing 2 articles on GFG, each one explaining MVC differently. So which one is correct? if the first case is correct, then who is responsible for the rendering?

PS: I am working on a laravel project and need to know this information.

Comment: I guess it could be coded two different ways, or even the same basic code architecture could be conceptually illustrated in two different ways. The View code is always responsible for generating the user interface components that the user sees on screen. The controller passes data to the View and tells it to execute and render the UI (which would be a HTML document, in a web app). The controller might then take that HTML and return it in the HTTP response it gives back to the browser (although technically, it likely returns it to the webserver, which then passes it on to the browser).

Comment: Or you could argue that the controller hands over to the View, which renders some UI and passes it to the webserver directly, to then send to the browser. I think MVC implementations I've seen are more like the first picture though, to be honest.

Comment: Laravel is an MVC in that it uses Models, Views and Controllers, but the actual flow is Route > Controller > Model > View. Basically, when an End User navigates to a Route (or makes a requests via AJAX or similar), it is picked up by a Controller method (or inline closure, similar to a Controller method, just not in a Controller), which loads the required Model(s) (if any) and finally returns the View (or Response, or a redirect, which starts the whole process again, etc.)

Comment: Both approaches are valid, and which one is used often depends on the specific requirements of the application.

Comment: @matiaslauriti In *PHP*, it's quite the opposite. It's exactly the first image. I don't know no popular PHP software where View acts on its own. May be in another technology, like a desktop application, it's different. But for the **HTTP-based application** it's a controller who handles all the interaction with a client.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I meant the image, not the author's description of it. Either way, I did not fully read everything.

Comment: Do you want to know that answer for MVC or for Laravel, because those would be completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

In [this article on the Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), it says in part:

> In addition to dividing the application into these components, the model–view–controller design defines the interactions between them.
>
> - The model is responsible for managing the data of the application. It receives user input from the controller.
> - The view renders presentation of the model in a particular format.
> - The controller responds to the user input and performs interactions on the data model objects. The controller receives the input, optionally validates it and then passes the input to the model.

**Nowhere is mentioned which type of object sends the presentation to the user**

In reality both diagrams are technically possible, but the second diagram, which unfortunately lacks adequate description, is potentially less misleading. Data, typically in the form of a model object, is sent by the Controller to the View (there is another possibility, which will be described) and then the View uses that data to create the presentation that will be sent to the user. The View then typically sends the data to the user but it can also return it back to the Controller who does the actual sending. Only in that sense is communication between the View and Controller bi-directional. But in the end it is the View that has the responsibility of creating the presentation.

Let me elaborate:

**Controller**

1. Responds to events generated by an "actor." By actor I mean anything external to the application under discussion (e.g. a person, another application, etc.) that interacts with the application. So a typical example would be responding to events generated by a "user", such as mouse clicks, form submission, application to application requests. So a controller object clearly handles input.
2. The controller uses the input event to implement a "use case", which represents a particular usage (scenario) of the application that achieves some tangible goal. As such it makes calls to potentially multiple model objects that may know nothing about one another and is therefore performing business logic "at a higher level."
3. Finally a controller object in general produces some sort of result from calling model objects. Sometimes the controller then passes to a view that data and the view itself may send a presentation of that data to the user or return it to the controller for presenting to the user. It is also possible that one or more view objects have registered themselves as "observers" of changes to some model object. Then when the controller has modified the model, the views are notified and respond by asking the model for its data and then using that data to update its presentation without any involvement by the controller.

**Model**

A model object typically represents some entity in the problem domain, such as a customer, an account, etc. or a result generated from the execution of a use case. It performs the create, read, update and delete (CRUD) operations (data logic) on data that gets encapsulated as its state and exposes methods (business logic) that operate on its state.

**View**

I have already said much about the View in discussing the Controller, so please excuse any repetition here.

A result obtained by the controller generally needs to be "viewed" by an actor. Sometimes the controller passes dats to the controller, quite often as a model object, and the view then presents it in some format to the "user" (actor). For example, in a web application a view object might transform the model object into HTML and then send the HTML to the actor's browser or return the HTML back to the controller, which does the actual sending of the HTML to the browser. Or there could be multiple views on a single model object that are sent to the user, which occurs frequently in GUI-based application. In this case the view objects register themselves as "observers" of a model object and are notified whenever the model object has been updated. The view objects then retrieve the updated model data and use it to update the presentation with no interaction from the controller.

Comment: Data logic is not Bussines logic. It is exactly model logic! Data logic is queries!

Comment: @Alijvhr Thanks. I have been doing OOP since the 1980's and I have never seen the the phrase "data logic." But clearly it is should be a model object that manages CRUD operations, I will clarify this in my answer.

Comment: Hi, @Booboo . What do you think about this: the controller only updates the domain model and the view queries the domain model (by itself !) and presents the response to the user. If there are only reading (as _"R"_ in _"CRUD"_) operations, then there is no need of a controller at all.

Comment: @dakis In the general case a Controller executes a Use Case scenario beginning with a "user" (e.g. a person, application or timer going off) triggering input or an event that starts the Use Case running. The Controller responds by calling one or more Model objects or Actor applications (perhaps a web service that is external to our application) to produce a "result". This result might be a Model object or just a textual message. This result is passed to a View that uses it to formulate a response to the user. There is always a Controller but there may not be a Model object or View involved.

Comment: @Booboo I meant, what is your opinion about the following: Using user's input data, the controller **C**reates, or **U**pdates, or **D**eletes a record in a db (no matter how). Though it shouldn't expect a response from the db, nor should it fetch anything from db. This should be the responsibility of the view, instead. In the case that a user only requests a bunch of records from a db (e.g. just **R**eading operation involved), there is even no need to use a controller for querying the db, in order to just pass the result to the view. The view can do this with no problems by itself.

Comment: @dakis Then by my definition this "view" is operating as both "controller" and "view".  It's a controller because it is running the use case. This is why I said in my previous comment "... there may not be a Model object or View involved", i.e. the controller is also acting as its own view and just outputting "Operation successfully performed" to the user. But there is an advantage to having an actual separate view object that is passed True or False to signify the successful completion or not and then the view determines what and how it needs to pass this information along to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it should be the controller, but simply think of of who and where the `return` statement is being called. and thats the one who passes the response back to the requester, but the actual response structure is handled by laravel router, its the one that constructs the actual response headers and body

Here's an example you can argue with your ideas and who passes the response

```
// we could say response is process by closure/anonymous function
Route::get('/test-1', function () {
    return 'Response 1';
});

// we could say the response is process by response helper function
Route::get('/test-2', function () {
    return response(['test' => 1, 'test2' => 2 ] )
        ->header('header1', 'value 1')
        ->header('header2', 'value 2');
});

// we could say the response is process by response helper function but also calls the view method for the actual response body and status code
Route::get('/test-3', function () {
    return response()
        ->view('test', $something, 200)
        ->header('header-1', 'value1');
});
```

But normally in Laravel, you should pass the route to a controller which process the data then make a return statement, which you could say the controller is the one who make the response and if you want to return an html body then you should call the view method to construct the html structure.

i.e.

```
Route::get('/test-4/{id}', [YourController::class, 'method1']);
Route::get('/test-5/{id}', [YourController::class, 'method2']);
```

Then your controller

```
class YourController extends Controller {


    // return with view
    public function method1($id) {

        $data = YourModel::find($id);

        return view('model-view', compact('data') );
    }

    // leave laravel router to transform your data into a json format when returning to the user
    public function method2($id) {

        $data = YourModel::find($id);

        return $data;
    }


    // format your own json as the response
    public function method3($id) {

        $data = YourModel::find($id);

        return response()->json(['data' => $data ], 200);
    }
}
```

Take a loot at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses)

Its safe to assume like this

**who passes the response back to the user?** - Its always the router that handles eveything be it a string, json, html, files, exception etc. its the one that handles the response headers and body

**who made the response?** - whoever has the return/render statement or whoever throws an error.

**does view passes the response directly back to the user?** - always No, everything is pass back to the router which process the response. view is only a wrapper for dynamic html formatting. with the rise of front-end framework and even with laravel internal support for react and vue, view will never be use unless you use blade template

Answer (score 1):

Simply every interact with user is in controller.

As you get request call a controller function.

When you want to return a produced response either view or JSON or anything you do it in controller!

So your answer is controller. And you see it in both diagrams.

In first one controller gets view and sends.

In the the second one controller sends view to user and user interacts.

Answer (score 1):

In the Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture, it is the responsibility of the controller to receive user input and determine the appropriate response to send back to the user. The controller is responsible for processing and interpreting the input, making decisions based on the input and the application's logic, and then updating the model accordingly.

Once the model is updated, the controller then passes the updated data to the view, which is responsible for rendering the response to the user. The view receives data from the controller, formats it appropriately, and then presents it to the user in a way that is visually appealing and easy to understand.

Therefore, while both the controller and the view play important roles in the MVC architecture, it is ultimately the controller that passes the response to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It is always the controller, and it has to be the controller only. It is a basic principle of MVC. You should always hold yourself to the rules and sending response objects through the controller only.

Answer (score 0):

### Something for your knowledge

In Laravel, we do not need a `Controller` also. Because they have introduced a mechanism called [**Route Model Binding**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding), you can return data without controller support.

Example

```
use App\Models\User;
 
Route::get('/users/{user}', function (User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

---

Other than what I found, this was more accurate and detailed to the **Laravel Life cycle hook** explaining proper *MVC*.

[image]

Hence, when dealing with API(Laravel as API, Vue, React, Angular), we will no longer see **View**.

---

Read

1. [Laravel Request Lifecycle](https://dev.to/patelparixit07/laravel-request-lifecycle-195e)